# SQL query (tricky situation)

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables: **ORDER_INFO_TABLE** and **APPROVE_TABLE**

The first one contains the information related to "orders".. **DO NOTE** that a single order may contain different "order lines" (thats why you'll see the order number repeated in the image below).Also, there exist a field called "PRICE" (this field is not SHOWN in my image) and CANCELLED (order line status)

The second table contains the information related to the "approvers" for the different order lines. Inside this table you will see a field called "APPROVERID", ITEMID (order line id) and "APPROVED" (order line status). The approvers must check if the price is okay or not. If the order line is okay, the approver will put a number 1 in the field "APPROVED". If the price is not correct, he will put a number 1 in the field CANCELLED in the other table.

Take a look at these images:

[image]

[image: image2]

**I have tried without success to obtain all the cancelled orders (an order is cancelled when all ITS order lines are cancelled) AND the approved order (an approved order may contain cancelled order lines) for an specific approver**

I tried so many times, using count operator, left join but i am completely lost :(

Could you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have *tried so many times*, you should be able to at least include your last attempt in your post to show your effort, right? And your images are useless, because no one can use them to create test tables to help solve the problem anyway. Please [edit] to post the DDL for your tables, sample data (as text that can be copied and pasted), your expected output from that data, and your most recent effort to write the query yourself.

Comment: Thank you for replying!
This is not homework, i am studying SQL by myself and i got stuck on this example. My queries dont even run. Did you downvote my post?

Comment: I didn't say it was homework anywhere in my comment. Please read it again, and then [edit] your post as requested. I voted to close it as too broad because you've not provided the required information or your efforts to solve it yourself. (You can see the close vote count below the tags.) SO isn't a free code writing service.

Comment: What do you mean by *efforts*? I did the images by myself.. i just need a little help, thats all

Comment: Efforts are your attempts to solve the problem yourself, which you have not included. **Please read my original comment again.** *I tried so many times* when you fail to include even one try is like saying *Honest, teacher! I did do my homework, but my dog ate it.* If it's not in the post, it didn't happen.

Comment: My queries did not even run..this is not for homewrok, i am doing it because i want to learn and my textbook had this little exercise and i got stuck.

Comment: Please do not show sample data as screen shots. You might want to read https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/ for an introduction on how to ask a good question regarding SQL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My guess is this exercise is to acquaint you with the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT web_order_id
FROM ORDER_INFO_TABLE oif
INNER JOIN APPROVE_TABLE apt
ON (oif.item_id = apt.item_id) /* I prefer "USING" if DB allows */
GROUP BY web_order_id
HAVING SUM(cancelled) = COUNT(*);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!
Oh,yeah.. it does make sense!
Gonna try again :)

Comment: Dude, it throws an error: operand data type is invalid for sum operator

Comment: I think that while using this query i will not be able to obtain all the CANCELLED and APPROVED orders for a specific approver

Comment: @programming_always: it seems `cancelled` is defined as varchar if you get that error. Why are you storing numbers as a varchar? (It should probably be a `boolean` to begin with, but not all DBMS actually support that)

Comment: Hi, @a_horse_with_no_name
I dont know how to solve it :/

Comment: If `cancelled` is always either 1 or NULL (even if it's 1 as a string), you can use `COUNT(cancelled)=COUNT(*)`.